# Why does my Wordpress website keep going offline?

Tags: wordpress

I have designed and set up a website for a client at https://deabreuandcohen.co.za/. I have Jetpack monitoring activated.

I get daily notifications that the site goes down and comes back up again. The hosting reseller says it is the Wordpress website but I have updated everything, done a malware scan, etc and I can't see any reason why this should be happening.

What are my next steps to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of why your website is going down ,
i have done a small inspection on your website in the developer tools

1. when the website goes down it seems some documents are not loaded to the page .

[image]

Have you tried installing a web application firewall to your website , this could be indication of DDOS attacks on your website?

In Terms of security
Install these plugins

1. WAF Webapplication Firewall https://wordpress.org/plugins/web-application-firewall/
2. Cloudflare which enables ddos mitigation https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare/

Read more about DDOS Mitigation https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/ddos-mitigation/

https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/https/deabreuandcohen.co.za

Here is a free website scanner by succri and their results
[image]

Btw i checked the network tab
There are no traces for ddos but these would help you in terms of security

Possible security fixes

1. Your TLS Certificate is expired
2. Your WordPress version could be updated to WordPress 6.0 , but please backup your website first or download your theme and test it in a local development environment
3. You have no firewall installed ,
4. Add cloudflare to your website for free to apply ddos mitigation